# fetch mysql query with specific range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table containing `latitude` and `longitude` followed by `location name` etc
and my program wants to load the data that only shown on the display, so it probably like this

```
e.g -6.880713 < latitude < -6.90176 AND 107.599411 < longitude < 107.635374
```

how can I load data using that condition?

**EDIT**

damn mann! i know from couple of research i found when i execute `WHERE (lat < -6.90176)` it only shows up data that begins -6.9xxxxx when i search -6.8 result found 0 :D same case when i execute `WHERE (lat > -6.880713)` it only shows up data that begin with -6.8xxxxx and no -6.9 :D WTF i don't understand why this is happening ~~~ no wonder the data won't shows up...

Comment: i've tried using between before but it doesn't work WHERE lat BETWEEN -6.880713 AND -6.90176. with primitive conditional when i compare different column like WHERE lat > -6.880713 AND lng < 107.635374 it shows up data. but when i compare WHERE (lat > -6.880713) AND (lat < -6.90176) it doesnt shows anything...

i dont understand....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also work:

```
WHERE latitude BETWEEN -6.880713 AND -6.90176 AND longitude BETWEEN 107.599411 AND 107.635374
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "math style" inequalities in MySQL. You will have to do something like:

```
-6.880713 < latitude AND latitude < -6.90176 AND
    107.599411 < longitude AND longitude < 107.635374
```

`-6.880713 < latitude < -6.90176` gets treated as `(-6.880713 < latitude) < -6.90176`, where `(-6.880713 < latitude)` will be a 1 or a 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE latitude > -6.880713 AND latitude < -6.90176 AND longitude > 107.599411 AND longitude < 107.635374
```